# Azure functions github deployment from subfolder

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using Azure functions with GitHub deployment. I would like to place the function in `src/server/functionName/` within the repo, but the deployment works only if the function is placed directly in `functionName/`

**How do I deploy functions that are placed in subdirectories?**

The [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference/) states

> your host.json file and function folders should be directly at the root of what you deploy.

but "should" doesn't mean "must", right?

What I tried:

- Various combinations of locations of host.json and function.json
- In `host.json` I set `routePrefix` but it seems to affect only the function's URL: `"http": { "routePrefix": "src/server"  },`

Comment: as for me I've created a separate branch to work around that. i was unable to find any way to put them anywhere else

Comment: FYI - the `routePrefix` setting doesn't refer to file paths, it refers to http routes. You only use that if you want to customize/change the default /api route.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways you can customize the deployment process. One way is by adding a **custom deployment script** to your repository root. When a `.deployment` script exists Azure will run that script as part of the deployment process as detailed [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments). E.g. you can write a simple script that copies the files and directories from your sub directory `\src\server` to the root, e.g.:

```
@echo off
echo Deploying Functions ...
xcopy "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\src\server" %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET% /Y /S
```

If you don't want to commit a `.deployment` file to your repo and your requirements are relatively simple, you can also do this via app settings by adding a `PROJECT` **app setting** to your function app with the value being your sub directory, e.g. `src\server`.

Comment: The deployment script approach works! I'm editing the post to add /S switch. This copies directories, which lets you copy multiple functions at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `AZURE-FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH` variable in `.github/workflows/<something>.yml`:

```yml
env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: 'azure/api' # set this to the path of your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  DOTNET_VERSION: '3.1.301'  # set this to the dotnet version to use
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for the feedback! I edited my answer accordingly.